# Callback in Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, callback, fragment

When i try to add `ISurfaceHolderCallback` inside `callback` in Fragment,
i got an error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`

```
 public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.qr_main, container, false);
            var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
            var height = metrics.HeightPixels;
            var width = metrics.WidthPixels;

            cameraPreview = view.FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.cameraPreview);
            txtResult = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtResult);

            barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this.Activity)
                .SetBarcodeFormats(BarcodeFormat.QrCode)
                .Build();
            cameraSource = new CameraSource
                .Builder(this.Activity, barcodeDetector)
                .SetRequestedPreviewSize(height, width)
                .SetRequestedFps(30.0f)
                .SetAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .Build();

            cameraPreview.Holder.AddCallback((ISurfaceHolderCallback)this.Activity);
            barcodeDetector.SetProcessor((IProcessor)this.Activity);

            return view;
        }
```

Please help me.. thank you

Comment: Have your Activity implement `ISurfaceHolderCallback` as also?

Comment: problem solved in my way bro :D

Comment: Well, I'm glad to know this :D